# Meaning of “The authors must present insightful implications based on their experimental outcomes”?

Tags: meaning

I am advised to revise my paper about a novel clustering algorithm. From the responses of reviewers, I have this question:

```
"the authors must present insightful implications based on their experimental outcomes."
```

I haven't understood what the reviewer means? Does he ask about a real case study, because I applied my algorithm only to benchmark of the UCI Machine Learning Repository?

Available: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html.

Answer (score 0):

It means:

> "the authors, after careful thought, must list down the ways in which
>   the results of their experiments impact the field of study"